# Add items dynamically in ListBox in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, listbox, asynccallback

I'm currently developing a GWT application. The fact is my application gets some datas from a database. To do that, I created an AsyncCallback which works well. Indeed, in the OnSuccess() method of my AsyncCallback, I have :

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(Object result) {
   System.out.println("readAllAuteur() - Reponse recue");
   gestionAuteursGui.maj_liste_auteurs((List<TAuteur>)result);
}
```

And the maj_liste_auteurs() is the following :

```
public void maj_liste_auteurs(List<TAuteur> result) {
   for(TAuteur auteur : result){
      String resString = auteur.getPrenom() + " " 
         + auteur.getNom() + " (" 
         + auteur.getDomicile() + ")";

      this.lst_auteurs.addItem(resString);
      Window.alert(resString);
   }
}
```

So I get all my elements displayed through the Window.alert() method but my ListBox still empty. It's like the UI was not updated. Have you any idea of the origin of my problem and how to fix it?

Thanks for advance !

Comment: I see no problems in this code (except it's better to use an ArrayList instead of List for data sent over RPC calls). The problem is somewhere else. How do you declare lst_auteurs? Is this the only list of this kind?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Andrei. So lst_auteurs is declared as a field of my Composite class and is initialized in the OnModuleLoad() callback. There isn't any other list of this kind. My question is : if I do a call to the addItem() method of my ListBox or a call to the add() method of my VerticalPanel after the display screen is loaded, are changes supposed to be displayed dynamically or I missed something?

Comment: Yes, changes are displayed dynamically. You can add options to a ListBox after this ListBox was added to its parent widget.

Comment: And have you any idea why it doesn't work with my application?

Comment: As I said, the problem is somewhere else. I don't see a problem in the code that you provided.